# How to copy files with ansible relatively to the role?

Tags: ansible

I have a copy task inside a role and I was expecting that the `src` location would be relative to the role itself, not the playbook that calls the roles.

How do I make this work and use the files from `myfrole/files` from a task inside `myrole/tasks`, I don't want to include the role name as part of the path as it does not make much sense. If I do it will break if I duplicate the role.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

If you do not provide any path at all, just the filename, Ansible will pick it automatically from the `files` directory of the role.

```yaml
- copy:
    src: foo.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
```

Additionally, since Ansible 1.8, there is the variable `role_path` which you could use in your [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) task.

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/foo.conf"
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
```

Comment: What if you're not using roles?  (Should you always use roles?)

Comment: @alex You could use `{{ playbook_dir }}`. If you should use roles, depends on the size of your project and if your playbook should only do one small thing or more. Personally I have not seen a valid case to not use roles, other than quickly testing something.

Answer (score 38):

You wouldn't need to specify the path of the file to copy, as long as it is stored in `files` directory.

Here's how your role should look like:

```
my-awesome-role
├───files
│       my-awesome-file
└───tasks
        main.yml
```

And here's the way to call copy in the `tasks/main.yml`:

```
- copy:
    src: my-awesome-file
    dest: '{{ some_destination }}'
```

Comment: How can I copy this my-awesome-file from my-another-awesome-role, without this new role defining files/my-awesome-file? Trying to avoid maintaining 2 copies of same config file in my case and both roles needs to ensure the first exist before an action that depends upon such my-awesome-file's copy/file contents